# mySql much slower in node js than in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, node.js, performance

I have got a SQL query which runs a lot slower in nodeJs with mysql module than in mySql client like phpMyAdmin.

I know that there is overhead for building the JS-objects but I cant believe this is the only reason:

Query:

```
SELECT `Groups`.`id`,
   `Groups`.`title`,
   `Groups`.`owner`,
   `Groups`.`isDefault`,
   `Groups`.`createdAt`,
   `Groups`.`updatedAt`,

   (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `View`
    WHERE `View`.`groupId` = `Groups`.`id`) AS `views`,
   (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `Click`
    WHERE `Click`.`groupId` = `Groups`.`id`) AS `clicks`,

   `Users`.`id` AS `Users.id`,
   `Users.UserGroup`.`id` AS `Users.UserGroup.id`,
   `Users.UserGroup`.`UserId` AS `Users.UserGroup.UserId`,
   `Users.UserGroup`.`GroupId` AS `Users.UserGroup.GroupId`,
   `Users.UserGroup`.`owner` AS `Users.UserGroup.owner`,
   `Users.UserGroup`.`createdAt` AS `Users.UserGroup.createdAt`,
   `Users.UserGroup`.`updatedAt` AS `Users.UserGroup.updatedAt`,
   `Users.Activations`.`id` AS `Users.Activations.id`,
   `Users.Datasets`.`id` AS `Users.Datasets.id`
FROM `Groups` AS `Groups`
LEFT OUTER JOIN (`UserGroup` AS `Users.UserGroup`
  INNER JOIN `User` AS `Users` ON `Users`.`id` = 
  `Users.UserGroup`.`UserId`) ON `Groups`.`id` = `Users.UserGroup`.`GroupId`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Activation` AS `Users.Activations` ON `Users`.`id` = 
   `Users.Activations`.`userId`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Dataset` AS `Users.Datasets` ON `Users`.`id` = 
   `Users.Datasets`.`userId`
WHERE `Groups`.`owner` = '939ab639-fd85-42ef-8c46-a7990215e26';
```

**In nodeJs with mysql module:  10sec**
 **In phpMyAdmin              :  0,15sec**

If I test the same query but without the count(*) for View and Click:

```
 SELECT `Groups`.`id`,
   `Groups`.`title`,
   `Groups`.`owner`,
   `Groups`.`isDefault`,
   `Groups`.`createdAt`,
   `Groups`.`updatedAt`,

   `Users`.`id` AS `Users.id`,
   `Users.UserGroup`.`id` AS `Users.UserGroup.id`,
   `Users.UserGroup`.`UserId` AS `Users.UserGroup.UserId`,
   `Users.UserGroup`.`GroupId` AS `Users.UserGroup.GroupId`,
   `Users.UserGroup`.`owner` AS `Users.UserGroup.owner`,
   `Users.UserGroup`.`createdAt` AS `Users.UserGroup.createdAt`,
   `Users.UserGroup`.`updatedAt` AS `Users.UserGroup.updatedAt`,
   `Users.Activations`.`id` AS `Users.Activations.id`,
   `Users.Datasets`.`id` AS `Users.Datasets.id`
FROM `Groups` AS `Groups`
LEFT OUTER JOIN (`UserGroup` AS `Users.UserGroup`
  INNER JOIN `User` AS `Users` ON `Users`.`id` = 
  `Users.UserGroup`.`UserId`) ON `Groups`.`id` = `Users.UserGroup`.`GroupId`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Activation` AS `Users.Activations` ON `Users`.`id` = 
   `Users.Activations`.`userId`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Dataset` AS `Users.Datasets` ON `Users`.`id` = 
   `Users.Datasets`.`userId`
WHERE `Groups`.`owner` = '939ab639-fd85-42ef-8c46-a7990215e26';
```

**In nodeJs with mysql module :  0.23sec**
**In phpMyAdmin               :  0.0008sec**

Amount of rows in table:
Click: 500
View: 95k
UserGroup: 40
Users: 20
Dataset: 200
Activation : 200
Resultrows: 5.7k

Why is the first query that slower in nodeJS? As seen via phpMyAdmin the query itself is not slow. How can it be that it takes that much more time to build the object when using the count(*)? The amount of objects to build should be nearly the same? 10 seconds is really a showstopper. As the query in mySql client is a lot faster I think I cant improve it with indexes or other DB tuning.
All tests with same DB running locally.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `View` a `VIEW`?  If so, let's see `SHOW CREATE VIEW`.

Comment: How many rows in `Groups`?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: If some of those are many:many mapping tables, see the advice here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: Does that 'owner' have 5.7K 'groups'?

Comment: @RickJames View it not VIEW it is a table with the title View. About 40 Rows in Groups. No the owner has approx 30 Groups but every of the Users has about 10 Groups (M:M Relation)

Comment: Is the Query cache turned on?

Comment: Yes it is. But even using SQL_NO_CACHE has nearly the same result. Additionally both tests use the exactly same DB so it should not be any of the DB configuration things in my opinion.

Comment: (`SQL_NO_CACHE` makes sure that the Query cache does not kick in -- and make the time unrealisticly fast.)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I am out of ideas on explaining the timings.

Comment: Which library do you use on the node side to connect to the mysql server?